# Turning off auto-maximizing of windows in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic, maximized

I know this has been asked for other Ubuntu releases, but the solutions posted are not working for me in 14.04. I've installed CCSM and turned off the grid option, but the windows still maximize when dragging to the top of the screen. I've dealt with it for a while but it's getting rather obnoxious. Anyone else had this problem and come across a solution?

EDIT:

This is happening in Gnome Classic, but not Gnome 3

Comment: Did you try to exploit [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-to-disable-auto-maximize-windows-in-gnome?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying to switch of several options which didn't solve the problem, what finally worked for me is to go in CCSM to 'Grid', then click on the tab 'Corners/Edges', and change 'Top Edge' from 'Maximize' to 'None'. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Wow you found it... This should be the accepted answer.  I should add 2 cents: the setting is beyond unclear and should not have been enabled by default.  It is disruptive to some that are good at maximizing screenspace.  I would think any OS would want to keep skilled users happy too (even if that skill may be unique).