# Want to turn off auto-maximizing of windows in 14.04

Tags: gnome, compiz, window-manager

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS, Gnome Classic and I want to turn off the auto-maximizing of windows that occurs when I drag a window to the top of the screen. I admit to being confused about the functionality and meaning of compiz, metacity, gconf-editor, etc., but I have tried to follow the instructions that worked for other people with this same problem, and none of them has worked.

I tried using Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (CCSM) to change the Top Edge behaviour from "maximize" to "None" as described in [Turning off auto-maximizing of windows in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520264/turning-off-auto-maximizing-of-windows-in-14-04/544781#544781). I also used gconf-editor to set top_edge_action to 0, as described in [How to turn off Compiz's "drag to maximize" behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72452/how-to-turn-off-compizs-drag-to-maximize-behaviour?lq=1) . I also used CCSM to uncheck "Maximize Vertically if Screen edge hit" as described in [How to disable the auto resizing of Windows when you touch the top or bottom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481627/how-to-disable-the-auto-resizing-of-windows-when-you-touch-the-top-or-bottom). I set the Grid Snapback Threshold to 0 for the top edge in CCSM and top_edge_threshold to 0 in gconf-editor (this was my idea; I don't know if it makes sense or not). Finally I used CCSM to disable the "Grid" feature entirely. At each step there was no change in behaviour and now I find myself stuck with this annoying feature. What else can I try?

Comment: Personally, I consider this a feature.

Answer (score 2):

I use 16.04  Gnome Classic, metacity.

Managed to disable the irritating 'auto resize' problem:

1. Open 'dconf Editor' ;
2. Search  for edge-tiling
3. Uncheck the corresponding box.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyboard shortcuts for window positioning instead of the mouse.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-(Numpad)<kbd>8</kbd> for window to top, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-(Numpad)<kbd>2</kbd> for window to bottom, etc.

For more search for the question regarding keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [hotcorners tool](http://sourcedigit.com/8266-15-powerful-unity-tweak-tool-customizations-ubuntu-14-04/) in Unity Tweak Tool may work for you:

[image: Hotcorners]

Disclaimer:  I have never used this app, so I am not entirely sure what its features are.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want, but unfortunately, that's for Unity; I'm using the Gnome Classic desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a similar config, with Gnome Classic, and hit the same problem.

Guesswork led to this gconf-editor solution. Change

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/snap/screen0/options/avoid_snap [0]
```

to

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/snap/screen0/options/avoid_snap [1]
```

Comment: Don, I wanted to comment on your answer, but I lost my Stack Exchange password and had to reset my account. As a result, I do not have the permissions required to add a comment. So here is my response: I tried your solution, but it did not work for me. Thanks anyways.