# How do I disable the window resizing when accidentally touching one of the screen edges in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window, window-manager, resize

In Ubuntu 18.04, when moving the windows there is a resize effect that occurs when accidentally touching one of the screen edges.  This control was available in CCSM and Ubuntu Tweak in previous versions with Unity.

I'm not finding it in GNOME Tweaks.  I also searched the repository with:

```
apt search ubuntu.*tweak
```

Comment: Related (but not same): [How do I disable auto-maximizing of newly launched windows in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/q/154377/480481)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
```

You may also have to run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

Comment: How is this different from in CompizConfig Settings Manager setting `Grid => Corners/Edges => Top Edge` to None? This change in CCSM used to did the trick for 16.04 but not in 18.04

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf Because 18.04 has GNOME + Mutter (by default} whereas 16.04 has Unity + Compiz, two quite different things.

Comment: So, is there a Mutter tweak tool?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just upgraded an old 16.x machine to 20, and now compiz only crashes, so I'm forced to use PoC Gnome. Why on earth isn't this in a proper graphical configuration?

Comment: This worked great for me in Ubuntu 18.04. I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa desktop and **Ubuntu 20.04 introduced a new auto-maximize wrinkle**. I wrote up a complete answer to this in [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-do-i-disable-auto-maximizing-of-newly-launched-windows-in-gnome)

Comment: @RobinHsu `dconf-editor` will allow you to tweak mutter properties. Navigate to schema `org.gnome.mutter`.

Comment: This answer solves VMWare 16 malfunctioning move/resize bug with Ubuntu 22.04 as host.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Gnome have "Settings Editor" like XFCE (Xubuntu) (It has additional settings in text format for things like Thunar, XFWM4, ristretto, Displays, along with all the XFCE applications.
The setting in that is in XFWM4 Uncheck "tile on move"