# How to disable auto-maximize new window in 18.10 (GNOME)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window, resize, 18.10

On any 18.10 application when I have an open window which is very wide and I then open a new window of same application the new window will auto maximize its size.   How can I disable this auto-maximize on new window creation? If it's possible, I wish to disable any type of auto-maximize window behavior

I tried following suggested solution from 18.04 which fails to work on 18.10 :

> Open Terminal and run
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
> ```
>
> You may also have to run
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
> ```

[(18.04) How to disable the window resizing when accidentally touching one of the screen edges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029168/18-04-how-to-disable-the-window-resizing-when-accidentally-touching-one-of-the)

Comment: The question you linked looks somewhat different. It asks for a way to disable maximising windows when you drag a window to the top and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the below command to set auto-maximize to false

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```

[image]

Comment: this no longer works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: and does not work on 18.04 as well. Also edge tiling option does not appear in Tweaks. How can we solve this? The auto sizing drives me nuts.

Comment: It worked for me on 18.04.

Comment: I have written up an answer for getting the above commands to work in 18.04 and 20.04. It is too long to put in a comment. This question is no longer accepting answers. Here is the link to that answer: [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-do-i-disable-auto-maximizing-of-newly-launched-windows-in-gnome/1384973#1384973)

Comment: @Noel - I have written up a possible answer that might help you. It has additional information. The commands given above and in my answer are the same. These commands have to be run in the terminal. Here is the link to that answer: [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-do-i-disable-auto-maximizing-of-newly-launched-windows-in-gnome/1384973#1384973)