After changing "Initial terminal size" GNOME terminal opens maximized. How can I prevent this?
As the title mentions, I tried changing the "Initial terminal size" inside the profile settings. If I go above 101 columns or 30 rows, the terminal will start maximized. If I toggle the maximize button, it will go back to the size I've set in the profile. Going to the Advanced menu and selecting a size like 132x24 or 132x43 changes the size without maximizing the terminal, so why does entering such values in the "Initial terminal size" fields makes the terminal open as maximized? How can I prevent it?
I'm using:
Ubuntu 22.04.4
GNOME Terminal - Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42
Thanks.

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-do-i-disable-auto-maximizing-of-newly-launched-windows-in-gnome

@amar Thanks, that solved the issue.
