new terminals cover entire screen instead of defined profile window size
I just updated to 24.04 and my terminal windows now open full screen. It's not f11, borderless full screen, but snapped to screen edges window full screen. If i drag the window away it transitions to the defined window size defined in the profile. How can i make it the smaller window by default?

Search is your friend, do search before asking questions, it saves your time, they may have already been answered. https://askubuntu.com/questions/154377/how-do-i-disable-auto-maximizing-of-newly-launched-windows-in-gnome

i did search, however i didnt know they relevant keyword to describe this effect, which would have led me to your linked post. thanks for a relevant answer despite the tone.

Searching gets better as you do more of it and if you are persistent, sometimes you do not know exactly what you are searching for but by looking at the answers you will probanly find a better keyword to search for and eventually it leads to you to what you are looking for (most of the time).

On ubuntu 24.04 :
I do not use window tilings so shut that off using   Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop -> Enhanced Tiling ->  set slider to off ( move to left )
To define gnome terminal default size -> ctrl + alt + t  -> to open up the terminal -> click on terminal hamburger menu at window top -> Preferences -> click on bottom left option labeled  Unnamed  ( or pick a named profile ) -> Text -> Initial terminal size -> two settings here for window width and height in rows of text ... adjust these values depending on your chosen font size and display resolution
on above terminal page -> Sound ->  disable Terminal bell ( this should be OFF by default dunno why it isnt )
Now terminal size will be set upon launch
If you have followup questions just update your question ... and yes 24.04 is even better than 22.04  !!!  Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04
